# Identify the part of speech of prepositional phrase

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Every lie we tell incurs a debt **to the truth**.

In the sentence above, what is the part of speech of the prepositional phrase "to the truth" and what is it the "reply" of?

The term *reply* here is a teaching term, like we say that *adjective* is the "reply" to "Which?" or "What kind of?", and *adverb* is "reply" for "When, where, why, how?"

Prepositional phrase is adjective or adverb

What type of adverb is --> to the truth

Answer (score 2):

You have already identified that the phrase is a prepositional phrase.

A prepositional phrase comprises a preposition and a prepositional object.

Here, in the phrase "to the truth", *to* is a preposition generally indicating a direction or dependency, and *the truth* is a noun (with its determiner).

A noun is a "reply" to "What?"

Comment: prepositional phrases are adverbs or adjective . So what kind of adverb it is

Comment: I believe that assertion to be wrong, or at least, it only applies in a limited number of cases. A prepositional phrase is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: no a prepositional phrase behaves as a adjective or adverb depending upon the usage in the sentence